# How to define a floating-point data type larger than 16 bytes?

Tags: c, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to do math calculations that they require more than 100 decimals of precision. C data types cannot go beyond 16 bytes (long double), so I cannot compute more than ~17 decimals. Is there a way to create a variable in C that can get more precision?

Comment: just use a library, e.g. `gmp` (gnu multiprecision)

Comment: You'll either have to use a third-party library (such as gmp as suggested by Felix) or roll your own multi-precision representation and operations.

Comment: FWIW, on several platforms, `long double` maps to the IEEE-754 extended precision type, with 80 bits or 10 bytes only. But for your purposes, you probably need so called big decimals or big floats, which can be found in third party libraries like GMP.

Comment: @Rafael: or, as John Bode said, write your own. I have done that, but not in C or for C. If you really want to do that right, it is a **lot** of work though.

Comment: Make `typedef struct { int sign; int expo; uint8_t digits[101]; } Rafael_float;`  and spend hundreds of hours writing and debugging code to support that  OR use [third party libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985658/how-to-define-a-floating-point-data-type-larger-than-16-bytes#comment86987958_49985658).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: IEEE 754 does not define any 80-bit type specifically, and I do not think Intel’s 80-bit type conforms to 754’s general description of interchange formats. I would have to check the details, and maybe it conforms to the allowable extended precision formats. What do you mean by “the” IEEE-754 extended precision type? Were you think of the Intel format?

Comment: Rafael, an alternative to using a 3rd party library depends on "trying to do math calculations that they require more than 100 decimals of precision".  If that is only a few functions like: initialize, add, multiply by an `int` and print. etc., than simple helper functional are reasonably code-able.  If this is the case, enumerate them, perhaps by posting the code temporarily using `double`?   This will help narrow the question.

Comment: @Eric: yes, I meant the Intel extended precision format.

Comment: @chux: most arbitrary precision types use 32 bit or 64 bit "digits" (or "bigits", or "limbs"), though. <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realistically you need an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) for some options. I personally have found [GNU MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/) to be fairly reliable, though I have also heard good things about [Arb](http://arblib.org/).